# Working with unicode characters in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unicode

I am passing my mysql query from PHP to mysql using mysql_query. Let's say I have two names  Théo and Theo in my database stored. Now I am getting both The names in each of these queries:

```
mysql_query('select * from names where name="'. utf8_decode('Theo').'"');
mysql_query('select * from names where name="'. utf8_decode('Théo').'"');
```

Can somebody please explain what's happening.
thanks :)

Comment: Why you are using utf8_decode ? check http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php 
Perhaps you have to use utf8_encode instead ?

Comment: Why is the database character set not just set to UTF-8? [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) by our very own @deceze

Comment: Also note that `utf8_encode()`/`utf8_decode()` are very nearly useless. They have a very specific use case, and it is very rare that you can be 100% certain you have that use case.

Comment: @Svetlio: Actually what's happening is: I am passing this search string from the UI. So when I receive it in php it becomes '%Th\xc3\xa9o%'. So I think I have to use decode now.

Comment: What default charset is your DB ?

Comment: Character set database is latin1